# Limit of sequences and integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, rational-numbers

If $a$ is a non zero real number , $x \ge 1$ is a rational number and $(r_n)$ is a sequence of positive integers such that $\lim _{n \to \infty}ax^n-r_n=0$ , then is it true that $x$ is an integer ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article on [Pisot–Vijayaraghavan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number), this is true. In fact, if $x$ is algebraic (not necessarily rational) then it has to be a Pisot number, and in particular an algebraic integer. A rational integer is of course a bona fide integer.

Comment: ok , but how to prove it ?